# Full Text Index on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

We can index the table by right-clicking on the table name in SQL management studio and clicking on Full-Text index.

This option is present but is 'disabled' (appears in light gray) in my management studio.

Also MSDN blogs points out regarding MSSQLFDLauncher. This is also absent in my case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345189(v=SQL.100).aspx

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Without sounding too obvious have you [installed the full text component.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: :) I tried installing all components and nothing worked for me. I might have done something wrong.

Comment: What I eventually did was to uninstall everything and re-install a 'feature-packed' SQL server 2008 R2. everything is in order now!